# Non-cash Working Capital

Tags: accounting

I am trying to figure out the massive working capital release for a commodity company. The recent drop in oil prices has led to major decrease in working capital and therefore an increase in free cash flow. However, it appears that the working capital reduced only on account of lower inventories - which is presumably an outcome of the lower mark-to-market value of the inventory.

If this is the case, i.e. the number of physical barrels of oil/products has not changed, but the inventory value has dropped, then there should be no release of cash. Why would then such a non-cash change (i.e. lowering) of working capital translate into a higher cash flow number?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit of accounting double-talk. The typical method of measuring cash flow is to start with net income (which includes cash and non-cash transactions) and back out the non-cash transactions. That is typically much easier that adding up all of the cash transactions. So a drop in non-cash working capital would "increase" cash flow in the sense that it's higher than it would have been without the drop, but it's misleading since it doesn't actually affect actual cash flow.  The drop also creates a non-cash expense, which reduces net income, which reduces cash flow by the same amount.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This was helpful, and encouraged me to do a deep dive. Very grateful. Also, made me realise how shallow my accounting skills are!